# Sorting an array by value in sub-array

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have been following the instructions for sorting an array by a value in the sub-arrays (from [Sort Multi-dimensional Array by Value [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699086/sort-multi-dimensional-array-by-value)) but it's just not working for me. See my code below:

```
$items[] = array("apple", "green", 5.13);
$items[] = array("banana", "green", 5.03);
$items[] = array("banana", "yellow", 6.13);
$items[] = array("apple", "red", 7.13);

function sortByOrder($a, $b) {
    return $a[2] - $b[2];
}

usort($items, 'sortByOrder');

foreach ($items as $item) {
    echo "$item[2] : $item[0] - $item[1]\n";
}
```

This code returns:

```
5.13 : apple - green
5.03 : banana - green
6.13 : banana - yellow
7.13 : apple - red
```

The expected result is this:

```
5.03 : banana - green
5.13 : apple - green
6.13 : banana - yellow
7.13 : apple - red
```

So what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why haven't you follow my advice on your previous question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24958027/how-to-order-an-array-by-value-in-sub-array#comment38791521_24958027

Comment: Oh, wow. I didn't didn't click through on the linked question to see that it was by the OP. Wouldn't have answered if I had known that this was a repost of a closed question.

Comment: Well, how should I have asked the question then? "How to sort by a value in subarray which is not an integer?" Would it have made any difference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace
`return $a[2] - $b[2];`

With

```
if($a[2] == $b[2])
{
    return 0;
}
else
{
    return ($a[2] > $b[2]) ? +1 : -1;
}
```

[DEMO](http://3v4l.org/gjVir)

Comment: Dang, I had just typed the exact same thing also found on `http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php` good thing I checked new answers before posting

Answer (score 0):

usort expects the function to return an integer. As you are sorting floats, the values are rounded, which causes the error

In order to get the result you want, you can use phps ceil function to  round UP the value:

```
function sortByOrder($a, $b) {
    return ceil($a[2] - $b[2]);
}
```

Comment: That won't work, `-0.5` will end up as `0`.

Comment: and 5.6 will be sorted equal to 5.7

Comment: @deceze can you actually replicate that? http://codepad.viper-7.com/L2iwVo

Comment: @KristianRafteseth see above comment

Comment: Hmm, interesting. Logically it *shouldn't* work, but for some reason it does. It does go haywire on HHVM though: http://3v4l.org/lfUcV

Comment: hm weird, somethings happening behind the scenes